# What is the difference between the methods process(Exchange) and process(Exchange,AsyncCallback)

Tags: apache-camel

I am trying to write a custom intercept strategy
What is the difference between over riding the method process(Exchange) by using a processor or over riding the method process(Exchange,AsyncCallback) using a AsyncProcessor.
When one i do i need to use.?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a copy of Camel in Action book then its best explained there in chapter 10. You can also find some details on the Camel web site, and the javadoc.

- http://camel.apache.org/asynchronous-processing.html